# System.out.println/System.err.println not working

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8

I have the following code:

```
  @Test
  public void testMultipleUpdatesSameTime() {
    final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(3);

    PrintStream out = null;
    try {
      out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(
          "C:\\pathToFile\\test2_output.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
      System.err.println(e1);
    }
    System.setErr(out);

    new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        gate.await();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      }
      System.err.println("FROM1: Starting at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
      System.err.println("FROM1: Thread with ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      }
      System.err.println("FROM1: Ending at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        gate.await();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      }
      System.err.println("FROM2: Starting at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
      System.err.println("FROM2: Thread with ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      }
      System.err.println("FROM2: Ending at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }).start();

    System.err.println("NOTHING YET");

    try {
      Thread.sleep(10000);
      gate.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }

    System.err.println("DONE");
  }
```

The result file is containing only half of the output expected:

- NOTHING YET
- DONE
- FROM1: Starting at: 1521464569722
- FROM2: Starting at: 1521464569722
- FROM1: Thread with ID: 11
- FROM2: Thread with ID: 12

Do you have any idea why the file does not contain the "Ending at" nor exceptions?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it (when removing calls related to `CyclicBarrier`)

Comment: do you have everything printed as expected? :O :(

Comment: Yes. I commented out all `gate.await();`

Comment: Try using `out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(
          "C:\\pathToFile\\test2_output.txt"), true)`  to set the autoflush flag to `true` . Also consider closing the stream once you're done (this action also flushes the stream).

Comment: shouldn't be from that because I was using the normal console system.out.println, before trying with files etc. it was working the same way

Comment: nope its not working with the autoflush.

Comment: What does `CyclicBarrier` do exactly ?

Comment: new CyclicBarrier(3) means that if we have 2 threads 'awaiting' at the moment they become 3 awating - they will be notified to continue, so it is used to execute 2 threads at the exactly same time (if you have 2 core processor and you are not so critical againsts the java "exactly same time" :))

Comment: something strange is happening but I cant understand what exactly yet

Comment: Easy. Both your threads are waiting at the gate, when the main thread finally releases the gate, it prints out DONE and ends. Then the other threads end and any finalizers may or may not run, and your file ends up with different amounts of data, depending on various things. So the code is broken.

Comment: thats great @Kayaman. I still dont know why the 'inner' threads do not continue running and printing, but they end with the outer thread? anyway.. adding a thread sleep at the end solved the problem. Do you know more graceful solution than the thread sleep? thanks

Comment: and you can post it as an answer btw as this is the right answer I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common occurrence that a file is missing some contents if you don't close the file after writing. There are `finalizer()` methods in many `OutputStream` subclasses that do close the stream, but they don't always have a chance to get called as is the case here.

The main thread releases the gate and quits immediately, the other threads quickly run their course and at that point the VM is closed and you can't trust that things finished correctly.

The original code is convoluted and it's hard to "fix" something that's broken from the ground up. For instance in real code you wouldn't have 2 threads competing to write into the same file. That just doesn't make sense.

In any case the best "fix" for this would be for the main thread to wait for the other threads to finish (instead of sleeping), and then close the file as below.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> ...
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> ...
t1.start();
t2.start();

t1.join();
t2.join();
out.close();
```

Comment: For instance in real code you wouldn't have 2 threads competing to write into the same file... file not but they may compete to write in the same entity (updating it) I am testing the spring default and broken @Transactional with these codes.

Comment: Broken @Transactional? You mean your broken code that attempts to be transactional, right? I recommend you read about it. You're only going to draw wrong conclusions if you write broken code and try to deduce things based on that.

Comment: no I am talking about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365965/default-transactional-in-spring-and-the-default-lost-update

Comment: Even if the `finalize()` method of a `FileOutputStream` gets invoked, it will only close the file handle. It will not flush the buffer of the `PrintStream`, in fact, it’s impossible to do that, as the `FileOutputStream` doesn’t even know that it is wrapped in a `PrintStream` (technically, it isn’t even a wrapping relationship, as Java doesn’t have that). Note that the `PrintStream(OutputStream)` constructor has been used, which turns off auto-flushing on new line.