# Default @Transactional in spring and the default lost update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

There is one big phenomena in the spring environment or I am terribly wrong.
But the default spring @Transactional annotation is not ACID but only ACD lacking the isolation. That means that if you have the method:

```
@Transactional
public TheEntity updateEntity(TheEntity ent){
  TheEntity storedEntity = loadEntity(ent.getId());
  storedEntity.setData(ent.getData);
  return saveEntity(storedEntity);
}
```

What would happen if 2 threads enter with different planned updates. They both load the entity from the db, they both apply their own changes, then the first is saved and commit and when the second is saved and commit the first UPDATE IS LOST. Is that really the case? With the debugger it is working like that.

Comment: Well it depends on the database and the default transaction behavior of the database. With `REPEATABLE_READ` or `SERIALIZED` it will work but that is a big performance impact. Which is also why JPA providers, like Hibernate, have a feature for optimistic locking (basically a `version` or `timestamp` column which is included in the update). When 2 threads do an update 1 will fail because the version numbers don't match.

Comment: The `saveEntity` is unnecessary. If `TheEntity` is a managed entity (as it should be, considering the method is transactional), any changes made to it will be flushed to the database when the transaction ends. The optimistic locking mechanism should prevent any lost updates though, as @M.Deinum said.

Comment: ye ye I know about persistent detached etc states I just added it for readability, but that is not connected with the question. The question is... why sprint @Transactional is not acting like everyone expects - ACID. All the developers around me that are using it from years, cant believe it is working like that but it is. the lost update is happening. Isn't it?

Comment: one way to avoid is by isolation = ISOLATION.SERIALIZABLE but it is throwing an exception so it is not so straight forward, the other is optimistic locking but also wants some changes.

Comment: @M. Deinum, that is very strange how every dev is scared of the slow SERIALIZABLe, but the fast is that it does not serialize the transaction (one after the other) It is fast and it just throws and exception if a transaction is having DML operation meanwhile on a read/used data.

Comment: so I cant believe how the spring users are using the default annotation and working with inconsistent data on the high load systems.

Comment: there is something very strange... developers are updating transactions with the posibility of lost update and saying "ooo no we cant use serializable it is very slow".. ok but when it is fast you are loosing 'the money'. Maybe we shouldn't be scared from the serializalbe sometimes.

Comment: You're not losing data.  You have two updates.  Your entity cannot be in two states.  I think what you're really wondering about is how the concurrency works.

Comment: How `SERIALIZABLE` is implemented depends on your database. Some will give you a row lock (others have to wait) others will lock a page or the whole table. There are other solutions then pessimistic locking (which is what `SERIALIZABLE` is and that is why solutions with optimistic locking exists and are generally faster due to less overhead on creating the transaction and locks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not terribly wrong, your question is a very interesting observation. I believe (based on your comments) you are thinking about it in your very specific situation whereas this subject is much broader. Let's take it step by step.

**ACID**

*I* in ACID indeed stands for isolation. But it does not mean that two or more transactions need to be executed one after another. They just need to be isolated to some level. Most of the relational databases allow to set an isolation level on a transaction even allowing you to read data from other uncommitted transaction. It is up to specific application if such a situation is fine or not. See for example mysql documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

You can of course set the isolation level to serializable and achieve what you expect.

Now, we also have NoSQL databases that don't support ACID. On top of that if you start working with a cluster of databases you may need to embrace eventual consistency of data which might even mean that the same thread that just wrote some data may not receive it when doing a read. Again this is a question very specific to a particular app - can I afford having inconsistent data for a moment in exchange for a fast write?

You would probably lean towards consistent data handled in serializable manner in banking or some financial system and you would probably be fine with less consistent data in a social app but achieving a higher performance.

**Update is lost - is that the case?**

Yes, that will be the case.

**Are we scared of serializable?**

Yes, it might get nasty :-) But it is important to understand how it works and what are the consequences. I don't know if this is still the case but I had a situation in a project about 10 years ago where DB2 was used. Due to very specific scenario DB2 was performing a lock escalation to exclusive lock on the whole table effectively blocking any other connection from accessing the table even for reads. That meant only a single connection could be handled at a time.

So if you choose to go with serializable level you need to be sure that your transaction are in fact fast and that it is in fact needed. Maybe it is fine that some other thread is reading the data while you are writing? Just imagine a scenario where you have a commenting system for your articles. Suddenly a viral article gets published and everyone starts commenting. A single write transaction for comment takes 100ms. 100 new comments transactions get queued which effectively will block reading the comments for the next 10s. I am sure that going with read committed here would be absolutely enough and allow you achieve two things: store the comments faster and read them while they are being written.

Long story short:
It all depends on your data access patterns and there is no silver bullet. Sometimes serializable will be required but it has its performance penalty and sometimes read uncommitted will be fine but it will bring inconsistency penalties.

Answer (score 5):

### Losing data?

You're not losing data.  Think of it like changing a variable in code.

```
int i = 0;
i = 5;
i = 10;
```

Did you "lose" the 5?  Well, no, you replaced it.

Now, the tricky part that you alluded to with multi-threading is what if these two SQL updates happen at the same time?

From a pure update standpoint (forgetting the read), it's no different.  Databases will use a lock to serialize the updates so one will still go before the other.  The second one wins, naturally.

But, there is one danger here...

### Update based on the current state

What if the update is conditional based on the current state?

```
public void updateEntity(UUID entityId) {
    Entity blah = getCurrentState(entityId);
    blah.setNumberOfUpdates(blah.getNumberOfUpdates() + 1);
    blah.save();
}
```

Now you have a problem of data loss because if two concurrent threads perform the read (`getCurrentState`), they will each add `1`, arrive at the same number, and the second update will lose the increment of the previous one.

### Solving it

There are two solutions.

1. Serializable isolation level -  In most isolation levels, reads (`select`s) do not hold any exclusive locks and therefore do not block, regardless of whether they are in a transaction or not.  Serializable will actually acquire and hold an exclusive lock for every row read, and only release those locks when the transaction commits or rolls back.
2. Perform the update in a single statement. - A single `UPDATE` statement should make this atomic for us, i.e. `UPDATE entity SET number_of_updates = number_of_updates + 1 WHERE entity_id = ?`.

Generally speaking, the latter is much more scalable.  The more locks you hold and the longer you hold them, the more blocking you get and therefore less throughput.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the comments above, this situation with `@Transactional` and  "lost updates" is not wrong, however, it may seem confusing, because it does not meet our expectations that `@Transactional` protects against "lost updates".

"Lost update" problem **can happen** with the `READ_COMMITED` isolation level, which is the default for most DBs and JPA providers as well.

To prevent it one needs to use `@Transactional(isolation = isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)`. No need for `SERIALIZABLE`, that would overkill.

The very good explanation is given by well known JPA champion Vlad Mihalcea in his article: https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/

It is also worth mentioning that a better solution is to use `@Version` that also can prevent lost updates with an optimistic locking approach.

The problem maybe comes from wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems) where it is shown that "lost update" is a "weaker" problem than "dirty reads" and is never a case, however, the text below contradicts:

[image]