# JPA @Version vs @Transactional for lost updates

Tags: java, jpa

As I got it both annotations can be used to prevent lost updates from java code when an entity is read and updated simultaneously from two different places.

Am I right that they are interchangeable for this purpose and just rely on different mechanisms?
Can anyone explain the difference between and possible use cases for both?

Comment: In a nutshell `@Version` is used in entities to mark version field. Version increment is triggered before entity persist, update operations. More info here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking `@Transactional` is used in servises and rollback changes if exception is occured https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring

Comment: So then what exactly prohibits from using `@Transactional` for the same purpose and relying on the default RDBMS isolation level which ofc prevents lost updates for two simultaneous transactions?

Comment: `@Version` prevent user from making changes in outdated entity. Persistence provider match persisted entity version and version in database and throw exception if your entiry has older version

Comment: `@Transactional` allow you to configure rollback cases

Comment: > allow you to configure rollback cases\


Am I right that `@Transctional` is in the first place a means to declare a transaction in the java layer and only after it allows configuring tx behavior like "rollback cases" as you said?

Comment: For instance `@Transactional(rollbackFor = { ApplicationException.class, RuntimeException.class })`  rollback is occured if method annotated this way throws `ApplicationException` or `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Found related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365965/default-transactional-in-spring-and-the-default-lost-update/60856263#60856263

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: yes, it is possible to rely on `@Transactional` to prevent lost updates as well as on `@Version`.

I made a test with the following scenario:
1. Thread A selects an entity E
2. Thread B selects the same entity
3. Thread A updates the entity in the following manner: increment field `E.a++` and saves the entity.
4. Thread B does the same.
This situation obviously leads to the problem known as "lost update", because in the end field gets incremented only once, not twice (as expected).

I was expecting that putting `@Transactional` on the method that performs the "select, update and save" actions will prevent this situation. Actually it worked out but only when I set the isolation level for the `@Transactional` to `REPEATABLE_READ`. After I did that an exception occurred while persisting the entity from the second thread.

My assumption was wrong only in the part that I assumed "lost updates" are impossible with the default isolation level (I tested with Postgres).
 This is not so!

The good article that I found while digging into the problem is this one from Vlad Mihalcea:
https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/

He exactly explains the "lost update" problem and all possible solutions that include:

1. `isolation level = REPEATABLE_READ` which is possible ofc with `@Transactional`

2. MVCC which is possible exactly with `@Version`

So again, to sum up, both approaches are possible to solve this particular problem.

Comment: I assume you were using PostgreSQL. This is because MySQL by default uses REPEATABLE_READ as the isolation level, whereas PostgreSQL uses READ_COMMITTED as the default level. And both these default levels are susceptible to lost updates due to the implementation strategies used by these DBs. Hence, to avoid lost updates, we need a higher isolation level. For MySQL it would be SERIALIZABLE. Please let me know if instead it was MySQL that you were using.